# Retrieving List Items using REST services in NAPA app

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, office-365, rest, client-object-model

I tried retrieving List items from the List(Marketplace) I created in the Hostweb using REST services in NAPA app , Set the permissions for Web, Site Collection, List to Full Control, Please helpe me what is blocking me!! I see that the Error code is executing, I tried adding alert in SuccessHandler but it doesn't show.. Any Help is appreciated

Code in **App.js** :

```
'use strict';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

(function () {

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is 
// needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
    getUserName();
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl  = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getlistitems);
});
 function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) 
 {
var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) 
  {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
           return singleParam[1];
      }
  }

  function getlistitems() 
  {
    // executor: The RequestExecutor object
    // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

// Issue the call against the app web.
// To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
//      appweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
// The response formats the data in the JSON format.
// The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
//      sucess and error events respectively.
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Marketplace')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });

}

// Function to handle the success event.
// Prints the data to the page.
  function successHandler(data) 
   {

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
var marketplaceHTML = "";
var results = jsonObject.d.results;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
  {
    marketplaceHTML = marketplaceHTML + "<p><h1>" + results[i].Title + "</h1>" +   results[i].Description + "</p><hr>";
      }

document.getElementById("renderMarketplace").innerHTML = marketplaceHTML;

   }

// Function to handle the error event.
// Prints the error message to the page.
  function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) 
   {
    document.getElementById("renderMarketplace").innerText = "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
   }



// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get 
// the current users information
function getUserName() {
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}

})();
```

Code in **Default.aspx**

I have just added the below Div with ID "renderMarketplace"

```
<div>
    <p id="message">
        <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
        initializing...
    </p>
</div>
<div id="renderMarketplace"></div>
```

Error I get:

[image]

Comment: Have you added in the listname var to Nadeem's code which is correct. Also check the name of your list. S

Comment: I passed List name as below, I don't think I need to attach the listname to a variable and call it in my function   url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Marketplace')/items",

Comment: Well in Nadeem's code yes you do. The error you got was saying that the list was not found...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// READ opperation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// siteurl: The url of the site that the list is in.
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function getListItems(listName, siteurl, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}

// CREATE Operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// siteurl: The url of the site that the list is in. // title: The value of the title field for the new item
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function createListItemWithDetails(listName, siteUrl, title, success, failure) {

    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": title
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx

Following post will show you how to create an app using NAPA and client object model. You can replace the client object code and use REST
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-develop-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: The answer of Nadeem in above is right for your situation and you can refer here for completely basic operations using Sharepoint 2013 RESTs endpoint. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx)

Comment: Nadeem - Thanks for your help, it really helped me understand how it goes.But Apologies!! I am trying NAPA app with JSOM and REST services for first time... I made edits to the above question... Let me know if I am doing anything wrong here

Comment: Mike- Appreciate your help, i have tried the above way.. let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: You need to use AppContextSite(@target) when constructing a list url of the host web in REST. See this example: http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/cross-domain-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-rest/

Comment: I added the same but i get the same error..  What Should be @target?

Comment: I think I am not able to call SP.RequestExecutor in this piece of code, I don't get an intellisense for "RequestExecutor" after "SP." . Is this related to the error I get?

Comment: Nadeem- I was able to successfully retrieve list items , What you said is correct, we need to add <app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getBytTitle('ListName')/items?@target='<host web url>'when acccessing the List in HostWeb ..Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. You can mark it as answer or upvote it.